# Which UI framework is good to develop mobile and web apps

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, mobile, ionic-framework, desktop-application

I want to develop one project for mobile and desktop app.

Please suggest me which framework can i choose for develop the apps.

Ionic will support for mobile and desktop?

Jquery mobile will support for mobile and desktop?

Bootstrap will support for mobile and desktop?

if any other framework, please suggest me which one i can go..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Ionic` is `SDk for hybrid mobile application development`. It is not for desktop applications.

`Jquery mobile` is again for mobile and not for desktop.

`Bootstrap` is a css framework which is responsive so it will support both mobile and desktop.

Comment: Any other good framework is available to support mobile and desktop apps

Comment: Look for `zurb foundation`

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is the best mobile ui framework that is build with top of angular.js and now angular team rebuild their framework from group up and created angular 2 with lot of changes, like that ionic team rebuild their own and came up with ionic 2 with amazing features.

For more details please check the below link.

https://sourcefreeze.com/best-mobile-ui-frameworks-using-html5-css-and-js/